# Jupyter notebook slides use cell output as slide

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, slideshow, ipywidgets

I'm making slides with jupyter notebook. For one slide I made a nice little interactive plot with ipython widgets. However the interactive plot is  a cell's **output** not input. Is there a way to capture that cell's output an use it as a slide?

Comment: You might have to make sure that you save the widget state to the notebook first. Try the "Widget" menu on the top, and then "Save widget state" (or something similar).

Comment: I found that it was easier to just use plotly. I tried to use the "save widget state" option, but when I used nbconvert to change the notebook to slides the widget wasn't part of the document. Thanks for the suggestion though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Which plotting library did you use previously?

Comment: Just matplotlib with the ipywidgets library to make an interactive widget